# How do you get proxy integration in scrapy-playwright working?

Tags: proxy, scrapy, playwright

I'm trying to set up proxy for scrapy-playwright but always get the error

```
playwright._impl._api_types.Error: net::ERR_TIMED_OUT at http://whatismyip.com/
=========================== logs ===========================
navigating to "http://whatismyip.com/", waiting until "load"
```

when executing the code:

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request
from scrapy_playwright.page import PageMethod


class ProxySpider(Spider):
    name = "check_proxy_ip"
    custom_settings = {
        "PLAYWRIGHT_LAUNCH_OPTIONS": {
            "proxy": {
                "server": "http://host:port",
                "username": "user",
                "password": "pass",
            },
        },
        "PLAYWRIGHT_DEFAULT_NAVIGATION_TIMEOUT": "300000",
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        yield Request("http://whatismyip.com",
                      meta=dict(
                          playwright=True,
                          playwright_include_page=True,
                          playwright_page_methods=[PageMethod('wait_for_selector', 'span.ipv4-hero')]
                      ),
                      callback=self.parse,
                      )

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.text)
```

The proxies tried are paid and working as checked, and the `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` in `settings.py` is set to `DOWNLOAD_DELAY=30`. This happens whether `PLAYWRIGHT_DEFAULT_NAVIGATION_TIMEOUT` is set to 0, 10000, or 300000 (as copied in the code above). What is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Playwright also supports providing proxy on context creation time, as given below.

```
                  meta=dict(
                      playwright=True,
                      playwright_include_page=True,
                      playwright_page_methods=[PageMethod('wait_for_selector', 'span.ipv4-hero')],
                      playwright_context_kwargs = dict(
                          proxy = dict(
                              server = "http://host:port",
                              username = "user",
                              password = "pass"
                          )
                      )
                  )
```

If not created manually, Playwright creates a default context and reuses it for each request. For same context, `playwright_context_kwargs` option is ignored for subsequent requests, and uses same proxy for all new requests.
As mentioned in their [documentation](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-playwright)

> Please note that if a context with the specified name already exists, that context is used and playwright_context_kwargs are ignored.